# then is not a function AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm trying to create a new controller that will create a new quiz then add it to a module, the problem is that when I look for the quiz to add it in the module, I always get that the quiz doesn't exist, so I decide to use `.then (function)` to ensure that the quiz was first saved and the add it to the module. but I'm getting this error message: `then is not a function`
below is my code

```
var Exercise = $resource("/myapp/rest/exercise");
            exercise.questionText = quiz.questionText;
            exercise.answers = answers;
            return Exercise.save({}, exercise).then (function (result){
                var moduleExercice = $resource("/myapp/rest/module/exercises");
                moduleExercice.save({
                    moduleName : modulename
                }, exercise)
            });
```

Comment: Try this: `Exercise.save({}, exercise).$promise.then`.

Answer (score 0):

For then to work as a callback in your case the Exercise.save function needs to have a return statement.